# shortest code to encrypt a string

Tags: code-golf

Using a language of your choice write a program that takes a string as an input, and returns the string encrypted.

## Algorithm:

You should assume that each character is always encoded in a byte and is ASCII-based. The extended ASCII codes are mapped to whatever is the default code page in use by the system.

You should encrypt the code in the following way:
code of first character +1, code of second character +2, code of third character +3 .....

Extended ASCII codes are based on this table:
http://www.asciitable.com/

Shortest code wins.

Comment: If you're above 128 it's not ASCII. I have no idea what you're trying to say with your example of wrapping: please rewrite it to make it clear which values come from the plaintext and which come from the key stream.

Comment: Is the requirement to jump past 0 when overflowing byte deliberate? (The successor to 255 for a byte is usually 0)

Comment: Or perhaps it's the increment that is never 0? Eg. the chipertext can be any byte value but no char will have the same chiperchar as the clearchar? Could you make the 256/0 part more clear?

Comment: Encryption algorithms that don't have keys don't seem rather useful. In fact this is just hardcoding one key for a substitution cipher.

Comment: If you're above 255, it isn't even the OEM character set. Please read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html when you get a chance. I re-read it every few years. :)

Comment: This question has two close votes as "unclear what you're asking". I do not agree with these votes. Can you edit your question addressing the complains to ensure that no one closes it?

Comment: @Victor the problem is that I really don't get the above comments because as I see here : http://www.asciitable.com/ there are 'extended ascii characters' which are 255 . I don't know what other word should I choose. Probably 'encoding' as the above link suggests?

Comment: @user689 I edited the question. Let me know if you do agree with that or not.

Comment: @Victor, it also has 20 upvotes on a comment that says why it isn't clear, and your edit doesn't address that point.

Comment: Isn't this encoding not encryption?

Comment: @Mhmd: The "extended ASCII characters" there are not technically ASCII, hence the confusion. Add the fact that that the scheme outlined there is a non-standard one (Microsoft's "Code Page 437", which isn't even any of the standard [and typical] ISO/IEC 8859 encodings), and you can see where the confusion comes from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### GolfScript <del>20</del> <del>19</del> <del>15</del> 12

```
{0)255%:0+}%
```

This assigns a variable to the character `0`, which allows us to not define it on the first iteration of the mapping.  I love that you can do that in GolfScript!  Each iteration of the mapping increments the `0` variable, and adds it to subsequent characters of the string (which is treated like an array).

This alternate 20-character GolfScript solution using `zip` encounters an interesting issue:

```
.,,]zip{~)255%+}%''+
```

Try it [here](http://copy.sh/golfscript/?c=ImhlbGxvIHdvcmxkIgouLCxdemlwe34pMjU1JSt9JScnKw==).  [This standard online interpreter](http://golfscript.apphb.com/), however, treats `zip` differently for an array containing a string and an array.  See [this](http://copy.sh/golfscript/?c=WyJ6aXAiIFsxIDIgM11demlwIHAKW1sxIDIgM10gInppcCJdemlwIHA=) vs [this](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=WyJ6aXAiIFsxIDIgM11demlwIHAKW1sxIDIgM10gInppcCJdemlwIHA=).  I'm not sure if an alternate version of Ruby or GolfScript is being used, or which one is considered canonical, but the second interpreter can be resolved with 2 characters:

```
.,,[\]zip{~)255%+}%''+
```

I also like a different solution for 23 characters:

```
1\{(@.@255%+\)@.}do]''+
```

Comment: The first one gives me an error message? `undefined method 'rightparen' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: interesting - it works with this interpreter: http://copy.sh/golfscript/?c=ImhlbGxvIHdvcmxkIgouLCxdemlwe34pMjU1JSt9JScnKw==

Comment: Hmmm. [This](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=J2hlbGxvJwouLCxdemlwe34pMjU1JSt9JScnKw%3D%3D) is where I get the error; different versions of Ruby or Golfscript, maybe?

Comment: The more standard online interpreter (http://golfscript.apphb.com/) treats `zip` differently with an array containing a string and an array.  See http://copy.sh/golfscript/?c=WyJ6aXAiIFsxIDIgM11demlwIHAKW1sxIDIgM10gInppcCJdemlwIHA= vs http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=WyJ6aXAiIFsxIDIgM11demlwIHAKW1sxIDIgM10gInppcCJdemlwIHA%3D

Comment: @Gareth the new 15-character solution is cooler, anyway, and works in both! :)

Comment: What's the `''+` for? Mapping a block over a string gives a string already.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Cool!  The online interpreter I was using doesn't show that, but running the code locally works as you describe.  Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

## BrainFuck: 21

```
>,[+<[->+>+<<]>.>+>,]
```

Assumes EOF=zero

```
echo -n 'My secret password is 123456!' | beef encrypt.bf
==> N{#wjiym}*{mv36HJLNPR>
```

Comment: Nice. And the code is encrypted too!

Comment: "Obfuscated," not "encrypted."  There is no secret key.

Answer (score 7):

## C — <del>67</del> <del>56</del> 49 characters

During compilation it might warn that `q` is missing a type...

```
q;main(p){for(;p=~getchar();)putchar(q++%255-p);}
```

Thanks to Josh for the significantly shorter rewrites!

```
$ echo 'My secret password is 123456!' | ./_encrypt
N{#wjiym}*{m����v3}�6HJLNPR>(
```

Confirm it handles the rollover from 255 to 1 correctly by encrypting 343 `x`s and checking for no `x`s in the output:

```
$ echo xxxxxxx | sed -e 's/x/xxxxxxx/g' -e 's/x/xxxxxxx/g' | ./_encrypt | grep -o x | wc -l
0
```

Comment: You can make this quite a bit shorter: `q;main(p){for(;p>0;q*=q<255)putchar(++q+(p=getchar()));}`

Comment: Wow, I'm always amazed at what people can do with normally verbose languages! Is it okay to revise my submission using it?

Comment: Go right ahead, that's why I posted it!

Comment: Would `k;main(i){putchar((k=getchar())+i);k^-1&&main(i+1);}` work?

Comment: @Oberon - almost, but in the `xxx` test it detects an `x` in the output.

Comment: If we can ignore integer overflow (input larger than 2^32 characters) this should work: `q;main(p){for(;p>0;)putchar(++q%256+(p=getchar()));}`

Comment: @Josh - almost, but seeing an `x` in the `xxx` test.

Comment: @YiminRong `x`s should be okay. The wrapping back to one instead of zero should just mean that there are no ASCII 0 characters in the output. Though the spec is not very clear.

Comment: @Gareth - I don't think that's what he means. If you encrypt and it gives 0, then "correct" it to 1, then accurate decryption isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @YiminRong It isn't at all clear what the OP means in this regard so either one of us may be correct here. My understanding is that each character in the string has its index (1-based) added to it. Any resulting values over 255 (outside the 1-byte range) should then wrap down to 1 (rather than 0 which would be easier).

Comment: You can test for `EOF` by `~p`. And I think you can also make the condition `p=~getchar()` and then use `++q+~p` (saving parentheses).

Comment: Using @ugoren's recommendations I can get it down to 49 characters, passing both test cases: `q;main(p){for(;p=~getchar();)putchar(q++%255-p);}`

Comment: @Josh - Wow, this is approaching specialty languages length! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

## Befunge 98 - 15 bytes

```
:~+'U3*%1+,1+#@
```

Keeps a counter (starting at 0) and adds that to the `~` input. Then, computes `255` (as `85 * 3` in the form of `'U3*`), then mods (`%`). Then, it adds `1` and prints it, then adds one to the counter, then uses `#` to skip over the `@`. At the end of the input, the IP goes the other way and hits the `@`, ending the program.

Alternatively, if your interpreter supports unicode, this 14 byte (13 char) solution works:

```
:~+'ÿ%1+,1+#@
```

Sample run (in command prompt, so some of the unicode characters are actually some ascii value):

```
This string will be encrypted using the predetermined method!2.7182818284590452353602874713526624
```

Output:

```
Ujlw%y{zrxr,äw{|1tx4zäzèÆèÅüü>öôèÉèDÖÄîHÖ£ÉÉÆóöó₧¢íÖÖVñ¥¡ó¬á^pmwrzu|v~yÇ}⌂ä|üâüâåàëäçÄÄîÉïÄæÅöòÆò
```

Comment: @ArlaudPierre What are you talking about? Befunge is my favorite programming language.

Comment: Is ÿ considered one or two bytes? Its value is 255 which is within one unsigned byte...

Answer (score 4):

### J, 21 characters

```
a.{~1+256|(+i.@#)a.i.
```

Usage (borrowing Yimin's test text):

```
   a.{~1+256|(+i.@#)a.i.'My secret password is 123456!'
N{#wjiym}*{m????v3}?6HJLNPR>
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, 90c

```
t.split("").map(function(c,a){return String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0)+a+1)}).join("")
```

```
[].map.call(t,function(c,a){return String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0)+a%255+1)}).join("")
```

[Fiddledee](http://jsfiddle.net/z92nQ/1/)

Comment: Your code doesn't wrap after 255 chars, it needs to be this: `.split("").map(function(c,a){return String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0)+a%255+1)}).join("")`

Comment: You can also do this and save 1 character: `[].map.call(t,function(c,a){return String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0)+a%255+1)}).join("")`

Comment: @A.M.K: Nice.. ducktyping the string, very clever! 
Forgot the modulus -.-

Comment: @micha I will try to understand what you write later. But I can see that you can drop that `0` in `.charCodeAt(0)` and save one char.

Comment: You don't need the `0` in `c.charCodeAt` and in EcmaScript 6 (supported in Firefox & Google Chrome), you can make it even shorter: `[].map.call(t,(c,a)=>String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt()+a%255+1)}).join("")`

Comment: You can even modify the original string: `[].map.call(t,(c,a)=>t[a]=String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt()+a%255+1)});t`

Answer (score 3):

## Python2.7 (67 chars)

```
import sys;print''.join([chr((ord(x)+1)%256)for x in sys.argv[1]])
```

Answer (score 3):

## **Javascript/JScript: 72 to 105 chars**

Here is a Javascript/JScript attempt at making a version of this code.

I'm aware that there is another Javascript code, but that one relies on recent Javascript implementations.

That is a bad thing!!!

That code is invalid in ie8< without polyfills.

Here is my version:

```js
function $(c){for(var i=0,l=c.length,o='';i<l;o+=String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(i++)+i&255));return o;}
//function call, 105 chars, absolutely valid!

function $(c){for(i=0,l=c.length,o='';i<l;o+=String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(i++)+i&255));return o;}
//function call, no var keyword, 101 chars, completely valid!

function $(c){for(i=0,l=c.length,o='';i<l;o+=String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(i++)+i));return o;}
//function call, 97 chars, most likely invalid!

c='';//here goes input, output is in var `o`, dont count this line
for(i=0,l=c.length,o='';i<l;o+=String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(i++)+i&255));
//no function call, input goes to var c, 77 chars of pure working code! valid for sure!

c='';//here goes input, output is in var `o`, dont count this line
for(i=0,l=c.length,o='';i<l;o+=String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(i++)+i));
//no function call, input goes to var c, no char wrapping after 255, 73 chars of probably invalid code
```

---

@toothbrush gave me this answer:

```js
i=0;while(i<c.length)c[i]=String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(i++)+i%255+1)
```

It changes the original string and is only **72** bytes!

I don't know why he has `%255+1` in the end when `&255` does the same job, is faster and shorter.

But I will keep the original answer intact.

---

Consider this and test it with a Javascript/JScript interpreter.

I know that the 73 char version and the 97 char function call version will be invalid, but its still here!

If you will be using the code in a production environment (website), use the 105 chars long and consider changing the function name to something else (or you might have problems with jQuery and MooTools).

Comment: **The 73 character version can be even shorter:** `i=0;while(i<c.length)c[i]=String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(i++)+i)`.
**To properly handle the wrapping of the numbers:** `i=0;while(i<c.length)c[i]=String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(i++)+i%255+1)` - *this version is still shorter than the current version*!
**Both modify the original string.**

Comment: @Ismael Miguel, No offense, but this is a code golf website; the code isn't intended to _ever_ be used. Therefore browser compatibility isn't a consideration.

Comment: @A.M.K  Does it work? Is it short?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, Yes, but you said `I'm aware that there is another Javascript code, but that one relies on recent Javascript implementations.

That is a bad thing!!!`.  All I'm saying is that since this is a code golf question, that isn't a bad thing.  I've even seen answers that use features that haven't been implemented yet!

Comment: Yes, but the upvotes are based on code beauty, not functionality. Basically: they are upvoting code that **MIGHT** not work for an undefined time.

Answer (score 2):

## Python3 (99 chars)

```
e=''
i=0
for c in __import__("sys").argv[1]:
        i=(i+1)%255
        e+=chr(ord(c)+i)
print(e)
```

### Example

`python encrypt.py password` outputs `qcvw|uyl`

Comment: The output for `password` should be `qcvw|uyl`.

Comment: Yeah, i fixed that, was a little bit to hectic :)

Comment: You can remove the `from sys...` part by doing `for c in __import__("sys").argv[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

### CoffeeScript, <s>73</s> 64 chars

`t.replace /./g,(c,a)->String.fromCharCode c.charCodeAt()+a%255+1`

<s>`[].map.call(t,(c,a)->String.fromCharCode c.charCodeAt(0)+a%255+1).join ""`</s>

Example: `"Test string".replace /./g,(c,a)->String.fromCharCode c.charCodeAt()+a%255+1` outputs `Ugvx%y{zrxr`

Coffee to Javascript converter (paste in right box): http://js2coffee.org/

As per Ismael Miguel's comments, this method should work in IE 5.5+.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby functional, 67

```
puts ARGV[0].bytes.map.with_index(1){|b,i|b+i%255}.map(&:chr).join
```

Example:

```
$ ruby encrypt.rb password
=> qcvw|uyl
```

Comment: [A new user](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59228/cia-rana) without the comment privilege suggested shortening the code to `puts ARGV[0].bytes.map.with_index(1){|b,i|(b+i&255).chr}*''`. [I've rejected the edit as per our policy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/suggested-edits-reject-golfing/1619#1619) but you might want to review it and edit it in yourself and credit them.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia 51 (-4 if in place is allowed)

```
g(s)=([s.data[i]+=(i-1)%255+1 for i=1:length(s)];s)
g(s)=[s.data[i]+=(i-1)%255+1 for i=1:length(s)] # in place version
julia> g("a"^256) # ^ operator repeats strings
"bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������\0\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\e\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !\"#\$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`b"
```

Comment: Note that `0` is not allowed as an encryptor, so in your example you shouldn't see `a` outputted.

Comment: Or maybe it is, once I reread the specs, it might be asking for a non-reversible encryption.

Comment: No I think you are right. I updated it, which adds a few letters.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <del>77C</del> 59C

```
import Data.Char
e s=h s 1
h""_=""
h(x:s)i=(chr(mod((ord x)+i)128)):h s(i+1)
```

v2

```
import Data.Char
e s = map chr(zipWith(+)(map ord s)[1..])
```

I am assuming that input doesn't need to be on STDIN.

Example run:

```
*Main> e "hello"
"igopt"
```

Answer (score 1):

### GolfScript, 27 characters

```
[.,,\]zip[{{+}*255%1+}/]''+
```

Hmmm...seems a bit long. Maybe I should stick to J.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>45</s> 39 bytes

```
gets.chars{|c|putc(c.ord+$.)%256;$.+=1}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Erlang: 60C

Not the smallest or prettiest, but this one can be run standalone in the command line.
Set T to your text.

```
{S,_}=lists:mapfoldl(fun(C,I)->{C+I,(I+1)rem 255}end,1,T),S.
```

Yields:
    "qcvw|uyl"

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol, 58 chars

```
s: input forall s[s/1: mod(index? s)+(to-integer s/1)256]s
```

Answer (score 1):

**Groovy, 53 Characters**

```
i=0;args[0].chars.collect{(char)it+(++i%255)}.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Dart, 68

```
f(s,{i=1})=>new String.fromCharCodes(s.runes.map((c)=>(c+i++)%255));
```

Example:

```
f('My secret password is 123456!');
> N{#wjiym}*{mv3}6HJLNPR>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 54 char

```
$i=1;print map{chr((ord()+$i++)%256)}split//,$ARGV[0];
```

Example:

```
perl encrypt.pl password
> qcvw|uyl
```